# Can't host/render images with GitHub

Tags: html, visual-studio, github, src

I am having a hard time rendering/ successfully hosting images on Github.

My github repository has the following link tree structure: **michaelamay/projects/post.html**
and there is an image folder with the structure: **michaelamay/projects/images/**

In my code i add that to the src in 3 different ways, none of which are working (see image below in line *24,25,28,* and *31*)
[image: visual studio code]

This is how the rendering looks. Just a picture icon shows.

[image: rendering of false image]

Here is the main page of the repository.

[image: main repo]

Inside the images folder.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why that is happening? I insert an image from a website and it renders fine but not when called locally from the folders its located.

Comment: Which file is the code in? (there is no posts.html visible)

Comment: Under the _layouts folder the post.html file is included.

Comment: try adding `./` as prefix to links

Answer (score 0):

Given that the file path of the post.html file is `michaelamay/projects/_layouts/post.html`. If you are trying to access `michaelamay/projects/images/img_forest.jpg`, the path should be given as:

```
<img src="../images/img_forest.jpg">
```

This is because the 'images' folder is not under either 'projects/_layouts' or the root of the project structure.
For more information, you can check [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp).

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. I also tried "./images" but had no luck.My guess is it has to do something with the Ruby on Rails code which determines how things render.